# Getting Typeahead.js, Searchkick, and Bootstrap 3 to work in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I've been trying to get this to work for the past two days, to no avail. I'm using Bootstrap 3, and I've tried both versions of typeahead: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.jquery.js

and an older version:

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/typeahead.min.js. And this CSS:

https://raw.github.com/grk/bookstore-example/master/app/assets/stylesheets/typeahead.css

My javascript is the following:

```
  $( "#user_search").typeahead({
      name: "user",                                                   
      remote: "/users/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"
    })
```

My model:

```
class User  
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :user_id, type: Integer
  field :name, type: String

  searchkick autocomplete: ['name']
```

In my controller I have:

```
  def autocomplete
    render json: User.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map(&:name)
  end
```

Config/routes:

```
  resources :users, only: :index do
    collection do
      get :autocomplete
    end
  end

  resources :users
```

And my view is:

```
<%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: 'form-control', type: 'text', placeholder: 'Search For User...', id: "user_search", autocomplete: "off" %>
```

I'm using the autocomplete results from Searchkick, which work fine when I do:

```
User.search("the", autocomplete: true).map(&:name)
```

In rails console, this gives the right results, and also when I retrieve the results from the REST url(/users/autcomplete?query=SomeQuery).

However, it doesn't work with typeahead. I've tried everything; even the basic examples that they give on their information page don't work for me (I even tried Bloodhound). Is there anything obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: This came up recently, I posted this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211680/typeahead-rails-not-working/22213397#22213397 Let me know if that addresses your problem

Comment: Thanks! That helped a little because at least now I get *something*, I get this error: Uncaught Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is required. I have: remote: `{"url":'/user/autcomplete?query=%QUERY'}`

Comment: my answer is geared towards the newer version of typeahead, i think that is using the older api